# state from switch component not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

**Description**

I am currently creating multiple switch components in a table using React JS. I hope to be able to change the value of the state. However, when I click on a switch once, it will add a new object with a boolean value.

[image]

below screenshot showing overwriting value

[image]

**Expected Results**

My expectation is that when I click on a switch, it will directly change its state. Here's the default state.
[image]

**Code**

Parent Code that handler event

```
 const [switches, setSwitches] = useState({
    lihat: false,
    tambah: false,
    hapus: false,
    ubah: false,
    view: false,
  });

  const handleSwitchChange = (event) => {
    const { id, checked } = event.target;
    setSwitches((prevActions) => {
      const newState = { ...prevActions, [id]: checked };
      console.log("newState:", newState);
      return newState;
    });
  };

...

 <FormCreateRole switches={switches} onChange={handleSwitchChange} />
```

Child Code

```
              **{row.slice(3).map((cell, idx) => {
                return (
                  <td key={idx}>
                    {row[2] &&
                      row[2].map((subIdx) => {
                        if (cell !== null) {
                          return (
                            <div key={subIdx} className="mb-3 text-center">
                              <Form.Check
                                type="switch"
                                id={`${subIdx}-${idx}`}
                                label=""
                                checked={switches[`action${idx}`]}
                                onChange={onChange}
                              />
                            </div>
                          );
                        }
                      })}**
```

**Question**

How to fix the issue and why is the event handler on the switch not changing the state?

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Additional :
I use the value state of switch component for inserting into payload mutation graphql. here's the payload mutation of graphql :

```
{
  "input": {
    "groupId": "ADM01",
    "permissionCodes":{
      "add": true, // assume the value come from switch
      "delete": true,
      "modify": true,
      "export": true,
      "view": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches state should be object with key is row id and value is value of each switch.

```
const defaultValues = tableDataMenu.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
    acc[cur[0]] = submenu[index].map(() => ({
        lihat: false,
        tambah: false,
        hapus: false,
        ubah: false,
        view: false,
    }));
    return acc;
}, {});

const [switches, setSwitches] = useState(defaultValues);

const handleSwitchChange = (id, index, key) => {
    setSwitches((prevActions) => {
        const newState = {
            ...prevActions,
            [id]: prevActions[id].map((i, idx) => {
                console.log('switches', index, idx, key);
                if (index !== idx) return i;
                return {
                    ...i,
                    [key]: !i[key],
                };
            }),
        };
        return newState;
    });
};
```

You can create **RowItem** component

```
const RowItem = ({ row, switches, handleSwitchChange }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <tr>
                {row.slice(0, 2).map((cell, idx) => (
                    <td key={idx} className="text-center">
                        {cell}
                    </td>
                ))}
                <td>
                    {row[2] && (
                        <div>
                            {row[2].map((sub, idx) => (
                                <div key={idx} className="mb-3">
                                    {sub}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </td>
                {row.slice(3).map((cell, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <td key={idx}>
                            {row[2] &&
                                row[2].map((subIdx, index) => (
                                    <div key={subIdx} className="mb-3 text-center">
                                        <Form.Check
                                            type="switch"
                                            checked={
                                                switches[index][tableHeader[idx + 3].toLowerCase()]
                                            }
                                            onChange={() =>
                                                handleSwitchChange(
                                                    index,
                                                    tableHeader[idx + 3].toLowerCase()
                                                )
                                            }
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            {cell}
                        </td>
                    );
                })}
            </tr>
        </>
    );
};
```

and use it in **FormCreateRole** component

```
<tbody>
    {tableDataMenu.map((row, idx) => (
        <RowItem
            key={idx}
            row={row}
            switches={switches[row[0]]}
            handleSwitchChange={(index, key) => handleSwitchChange(row[0], index, key)}
        ></RowItem>
    ))}
</tbody>;
```

You can check full source code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-shape-e7fmvl?file=/src/component.js:1237-1554)

Comment: Everything is working well, sir, but when I click on one switch, they all get clicked. I want to be able to click on one switch without affecting the others

Comment: @github.arief i've edited my code, please check again

Comment: sir, i realized something, when i click single switch, it log these value : switches 00lihat 
switches 01lihat 
switches 02 lihat 
switches 03 lihat , i want just one click switch, just print one value with index position clicked switch

Comment: @github.arief i've log it for debug in handleSwitchChange function, you can remove it :D

Comment: can i get the update value with logging like this : console.log(defaultValues.lihat); ?

Comment: @github.arief why do you need log that value?

Comment: yeah because i need to follow graphql mutation spesification

Comment: @github.arief can you try this console.log("switches", !prevActions[id][index][key]); [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-shape-e7fmvl?file=/src/component.js:519-573)

Comment: i'm edit the question sir